# IIS and Web.Management.PHP

Tags: php, iis, iis-7

Unable to use iisreset, because after using that I got something like below:

```
Attempting stop...
Internet services successfully stopped
Attempting start...
Restart attempt failed.
The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion. (2147943453, 8007041d)
```

in Event Viewer I got below event:

```
IISMANAGER_ERROR_LOADING_PROVIDER_TYPE

IIS Manager could not load type 'Web.Management.PHP.PHPProvider, Web.Management.PHP, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8175de49a9aec91d' for module provider 'PHP' that is declared in %windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\administration.config. Verify that the type is correct, and that the assembly that contains the module provider is in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC).

Exception:System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Web.Management.PHP, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8175de49a9aec91d' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Web.Management.PHP, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8175de49a9aec91d'
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle._GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.RuntimeType.PrivateGetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError)
   at Microsoft.Web.Management.Server.AdministrationModuleProvider.GetModuleProvider(String userName, String connectionName)

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].


Process:InetMgr
Connection:computer\admin
```

I opened `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\administration.config` but nothing found including `php` or `Web.Management.PHP.PHPProvider` or anything related to php

The only way to get IIS back to work is restarting server

Comment: Check this first, https://forums.iis.net/t/1239061.aspx?IISRESET+results+in+W3SVC+stuck+in+stopping+status+after+July+2018+patches

Comment: Hey @LexLi, your comment is my answer, please write it as an answer

Comment: I found something about notepad++. When I edited %windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\administration.config with elevated NPP, it shows me no PHP in the file, because previously I edited that file and removed that line and saved with npp (several weeks ago!). but when I opened file with another editor, here VSCode, I realized non of my edits were saved by NPP!!! NPP showed me its cached version of file for several weeks after multiple restarts!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Copied from the comment.)

Unfortunately such issues are caused by Microsoft's July patches, as discussed elsewhere ever the internet in the past few days, such as [this](https://forums.iis.net/t/1239061.aspx?IISRESET+results+in+W3SVC+stuck+in+stopping+status+after+July+2018+patches).

You need to uninstall the relevant patches to get the services back, and then read through the updated KB articles to see what extra patches or procedures are needed to resolve the issues.

Comment: Your comment helped me finding windows updates solving this problem (http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4345459) and no need to uninstall previous updates. just download & install KB4345459 and problem solved